# Back wp database lead to wrong skip

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have build wp on domain.com,and build other wp on 127.0.0.1. Now i dump database from my back end on domain.com and dump into mysql database on local machine with the command.

```
mysqldump -u root -p wpdatabase > back.sql  #after i connect the remote vps
#download the back.sql file into local machine with filezilla on /home/back.sql
mysql -u root -ppassword wp_test < /home/back.sql  #on local console
```

When i input 127.0.0.1 ,my wp is in good status,but when i want to login ,
input `127.0.0.1/wp-login.php`  in firefox ,
it skip onto `domain.com/wp-login.php`.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update all the references to `domain.com` in the database.  Check out [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RELOCATE` constant in `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'RELOCATE', true );
```

Then navigate to http://newdomain.com/wp-login.php and login. WordPress will automatically update the database. Unset this line after you've successfully logged in.

More information: [Changing The Site URL: Relocate method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Relocate_method)

Comment: Nice; that's a new one for me.  Though I just read _"Note: When the RELOCATE flag is set to true, the Site URL will be automatically updated to whatever path you are using to access the login screen. This will get the admin section up and running on the new URL, but it will not correct any other part of the setup. Those you will still need to alter manually."_, so other references will still need to be updated